Jenkins agent with custom docker image is not running. Error: "Container is not running"
Summary: On raspberry pi, linux debian, when i try use jenkins agent image "jenkins/agent:jdk11" it works fine. But if i try pull my own image from dockerhub (literraly the same), it give me error "java.io.IOException: Container is not running."
Problem in more detail: I try to learn jenkins. I use jenkins master in docker container on my raspberry pi with linux debian and was trying to use jenkins agent connected with socat do docker daemon.
When it works: If i use official docker image jenkins/agent:jdk11, i can make hello world.
Where is the problem: I need my own image with c++ tools. At first, I build simplest, image created with dockerfile without tools:
FROM jenkins/agent:jdk11

USER jenkins

But now i have problem in jenkins, because when i try to build simple freestyle project with my image from dockerhub, i have error:
java.io.IOException: Container is not running.
    at io.jenkins.docker.connector.DockerComputerConnector.createLauncher(DockerComputerConnector.java:195)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate.doProvisionNode(DockerTemplate.java:754)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate.provisionNode(DockerTemplate.java:682)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$1.run(DockerCloud.java:414)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

What I tried: When I i use jenkins in the same method on my PC with windows, everything works fine. I can make hello world. But i need linux.
I have no idea where the problem is.
Any suggestion?

You can use Jenkins's Docker integration to run build steps against arbitrary images (with some setup, which comes with some security implications).  Can you use this to avoid needing build tools on your agents?

Is that log from your build? Have you checked Jenkins system log?

Solution:
On dockerhub it was written that my image built on linux mint have ARM64 architecture.
But when i tried to run this image on my raspberry with linux, i got error:
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

When i build new image, with ARM64 it works:
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t your-dockerhub-username/yourimagename:yourtag .

